# fetching the id's along with phone number and gmtstarttime

Tags: mysql

I have input table as below

```
Phonenumber GMTSTSRTTIME    GMTENDTIME
989876758   20170101 11:15:00   20170101 11:20:00
989876758   20170101 13:15:00   20170101 13:33:00
```

and lookup table as

```
Intra_ID    Seg_id  Phonenumber GMTSTARTTIME    seq
1213    12131   989876758   20170101 11:09:00   1
1213    12132   989876758   20170101 11:09:00   2
1213    12133   989876758   20170101 11:09:00   3
1214    12141   989876758   20170101 13:09:00   1
1214    12142   989876758   20170101 13:09:00   2
1214    12143   989876758   20170101 13:09:00   3
```

and I'm expecting the output as below, as max(seg_id) followed by the intra_ID,phonenumber,GMTSTSRTTIME,GMTENDTIME

```
Intra_ID    Seg_id  Phonenumber GMTSTSRTTIME    GMTENDTIME
1213    12133   989876758   20170101 11:15:00   20170101 11:20:00
1214    12143   989876758   20170101 13:15:00   20170101 13:33:00
```

In this case, the phone number is coming on the same day with different timings so it became a unique value. when I try to join with the lookup table it is giving me the cross join values as below.

```
Intra_ID    Seg_id  Phonenumber GMTSTSRTTIME    GMTENDTIME
1213    12131   989876758   20170101 11:15:00   20170101 11:20:00
1213    12131   989876758   20170101 13:15:00   20170101 13:33:00
1214    12141   989876758   20170101 11:15:00   20170101 11:20:00
1214    12141   989876758   20170101 13:15:00   20170101 13:33:00
```

which is wrong.

please help me on this

Thank in advance

Comment: Does a given phone number always have just 2 records, or could it have more than 2?

Comment: sometimes it might be more than 2.
suppose if i have 3 phone numbers in input i'll be having 3 phone numbers in lookup  table as well

Comment: How does the query look like?

Comment: EDITED :Apologies as my requirement has changed based on data. In lookup table my GMTSTARTTIME will be same for that phone number and for that instant.

Answer (score 1):

The query is really just a basic inner join between `input` and `lookup` on both the phone number *and* the row number, as ordered by time in each phone number the group.  The problem is that there is no row number column in your tables, and MySQL does not support any `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function.  So, one option is to simulate the row number using session variables.

```
SET @row_number_1 = 0;
SET @row_number_2 = 0;
SET @Phonenumber_1 = NULL;
SET @Phonenumber_2 = NULL;

SELECT
    t2.Intra_ID,
    t2.Seg_id,
    t1.Phonenumber,
    t1.GMTSTSRTTIME,
    t1.GMTENDTIME, t1.rn, t2.rn
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @row_number_1:=CASE WHEN @Phonenumber_1 = Phonenumber
                          THEN @row_number_1 + 1
                          ELSE 1
        END AS rn,
        @Phonenumber_1:=Phonenumber as Phonenumber,
        GMTSTSRTTIME,
        GMTENDTIME
    FROM input
    ORDER BY Phonenumber, GMTSTSRTTIME
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        @row_number_2:=CASE WHEN @Phonenumber_2 = t.Phonenumber
                          THEN @row_number_2 + 1
                          ELSE 1
        END AS rn,
        @Phonenumber_2:=Phonenumber as Phonenumber,
        t.Intra_ID,
        t.Seg_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.*
        FROM lookup t1
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Phonenumber, Intra_ID, MAX(GMTSTARTTIME) AS max_gmt
            FROM lookup
            GROUP BY Phonenumber, Intra_ID
        ) t2
            ON t1.Phonenumber  = t2.Phonenumber AND
               t1.GMTSTARTTIME = t2.max_gmt
    ) t
    ORDER BY t.Phonenumber, t.GMTSTARTTIME
) t2
    ON t1.Phonenumber = t2.Phonenumber AND
       t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

Note that this answer is a good example of how to keep track of multiple simulated row numbers in a single query.  In this case, we can just use separate session variables for each row number.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Please give me time to check with the entire table.

Comment: Yeah with the first one i was getting wrong results, let me check with the updated one. Thank you

Comment: I'm still getting the cross join values not the required one, with the updated query

Comment: @Rajesh It works in Rextester and the logic is correct I believe.  As I don't have Workbench locally, I can't provide any more assistance other to suggest that you test each subquery separately, and then build up to my actual query.  This should reveal where your problem is.

Comment: The above query will work for single phone number.Thank You

Comment: Actually its a bit complex I feel,even I'm trying from my end.Thank you

Comment: @Rajesh I think I fixed it now.  The issue is that I was only ordering by time, and not by phone number.  Hence the row number was not being computed correctly (it was turning up 1 everywhere for this particular data set).  Just changing the `ORDER BY` in the subqueries fixed it.

Comment: it is taking only one seg_id and intra_id for multiple phone numbers(same phone number) at different tim. Thank You

Comment: No, I won't make any further updates unless you also update your question.  Show us _every_ edge case, explained with sample data.  This is _not_ the way to get help on SO.

Comment: Sorry about that Tim, will update the question give me couple of minutes

Comment: I updated my answer again.  I would greatly appreciate it if you would not change your requirements again, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But still I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Good luck, I hope you will find what you're looking for.

Comment: EDITED,Apologies as my requirement has changed based on data. In lookup table my GMTSTARTTIME will be same for that phone number (before it was different) for that instant. that is the reason i was getting cross join results

Comment: I got the solution. I have edited the above query and got the results fine. Once again Thank you for the help.